# iPhone how to make subview height same as parent view height using autolayout

Tags: iphone, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I placed `UIView`(child view) in the ViewController's view(parent view) in the `storyboard`.
I am using AutoLayout.
When I run the app on iPhone3.5" device, the parent view's height is 480, but child view's height is 568.
How can I set child view's height the same as the parent height using `AutoLayout`?

Following are what I tried, but no effect.

1) In the storyboard, "Equal Height" constraints were disabled.
2) I put the code in the `viewDidLoad` of ViewController.

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.view
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach top, bottom, leading and trailing with constant 0, multiplier 1.

The attributes will be that need to be set are the following:

```
   NSLayoutAttributeTop,
   NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
   NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
   NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
```

The method for this approach is:

> constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:

---

Another way of doing it would be using visual constraints as follows with the following visual format for Vertical:

> V:[yourView]

and the following for the horizontal:

> H:[yourView]

Note 1: The method used for this approach is

```
constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:
```

Note 2: Having no '**-**' beside it means that the distance to the superview is 0.

---

And the last way of doing it would be using storyboard. All you need to do is to set the approach 1 constraints for the view inside with regard to its super view and have the constant 0.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried to add 4 constraints using both of storyboard and code, but child view's height is always 568 in iPhone3.5" device.

Comment: What is your parent view? Is it possibly a Scroll View?

Comment: Both of parent view and child view are UIView.

Comment: That's pretty strange, do you have any other elements on the view that are dependent? equal height, width etc?

Comment: I uncheck "Autoresize subviews" of the parent view, and it works.